# How to hide dropdown and how to multiselect from dropdown?

Tags: laravel, laravel-form

I have dropdown list with weekdays i want to select multiple days, like 'Monday' and 'Tuesday' I have several question on it

- 1) How to hide multiselect dropdown? Because it is showing all list
- 2) How to multiselect it? should I hold CTRL to multiselect?
- 3) How it will be saved in database if i gonna put it as a string to same column i mean will it be like 'MondayTuesday', or 'Monday Tuesday', or 'Monday, Tuesday'

Here is my view

```
        <div class="form-group">
            {{Form::label('weekdays', 'Week Days')}}

            {{Form::select('weekdays',$weekdays,null,array('name'=>'weekdays[]', 'multiple' => 'multiple'))}}
            {{Form::select('timetable',$time,null,array('name'=>'time[]'))}}
        </div>
```

Controller

```
        $categories_name = Category::pluck('category_name','id');    
        $data = array(
            'weekdays' => [
                'Monday',
                'Tuesday',
                'Wednesday'
            ],
            'time' => [
                '2p.m',
                '3p.m'
            ],
            'categories_name' => $categories_name
        );
        return view('pages.clubs.create_club')->with($data);
    }
```

[see the screenshot to understand what i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3mxv.png)

Comment: For 1 and 2 point you can use jquery multi select plugin you don't have to hold CTRL for that case just seach and add ...now for the third point you can get array of categories and store into db as longText by doing this `json_encode($request->get('categories))`, then at the time of retrieving categories do this `json_decode($key->categories)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1 and 2, you can use the plugin called [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), it is well documented and very easy to implement.

For number 3 question, you can save it in json format on the database like so:

```
$days = "Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday"; 
//or $days = $request->weekdays;
$parsed = explode(",", $days);
$selected_weekdays = json_encode($parsed);

Model::create(['weekdays' => $selected_weekdays]);
```

You can then display the value on the blade by decoding the json string like so:

```
$selected_weekdays = json_decode($model->weekdays);

{{Form::select('weekdays[]',$weekdays,$selected_weekdays,array('multiple' => 'multiple'))}}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

It is advisable to install it using bower:

```
bower install chosen
```

To use chosen:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href="{{ asset('bower_components/chosen/chosen.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

{{Form::select('weekdays[]',$weekdays,$selected_weekdays,array('multiple' => 'multiple', 'class' => 'chosen-select'))}}

<script src="{{ asset('bower_components/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js') }}"></script>

<script>
    $(".chosen-select").chosen();
</script>
```

Comment: can you explain me how should I declare chosen in form? i have installed it using composer, could please show me how to show how to make it

Comment: @NurdauletShamilov - please check the update on my answer on how to use chosen